# Adding dropdown list to tutor lms registration form

Tags: plugin-development

Tutor lms plugin gives instructions of adding phome number field to its registration form as in this link
https://docs.themeum.com/tutor-lms/developers/custom-field-on-registration/

I have added dropdown list field that appears on the frontend yet I can't display the result of this field on the backend and I don't know what is the alternative code in the profile.php file and user-profile.php metabox file as mentioned for the phone number example on tutor website for the dropdown list field.

Would someone please help me regarding that. I am new to coding.
-------‐-----------
For coding I entered this code through code snippet to frontend
        if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
    {
      $aUniversities = $_POST['formUniversities'];

```
  if(!isset($aUniversities)) 
  {
    echo("<p>You didn't select any Universities!</p>\n");
  } 
  else 
  {
    $nUniversities = count($aUniversities);

    echo("<p>You selected $nUniversities Universities: ");
    for($i=0; $i < $nUniversities; $i++)
    {
      echo($aUniversities[$i] . " ");
    }
    echo("</p>");
  }
}
```

//Then I entered this code in the  registration.php file of the the plugin

'Select your University:

Ahram Canadian University
Misr International University
Other
'

---

I tried similarcode on profile.php and user-profile-fields.php (of the metabox) but they don't seem to work

What is wrong or missing? Kindly advise.

Comment: </div>
 
<label for='formUniversities[]'>Select your University:</label><br>

<select multiple="multiple" name="formUniversities[]">
 
   <option value="Ahram">Ahram Canadian University</option>
<option value="Ain">Ain Shams University</option>
<option value="Akhbar">Akhbar elyom academy</option>
<select>

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.